# Running multiple devices with calabash ios

Tags: ios, calabash

Have been searching for a workaround to run multiple devices with calabash ios. 
AFAIK, calabash ios uses port 37265 and instrument to load and interact with the app.
Instrument can also only run once at a time. I have read somewhere that we might need to use virtual machine, is that true? Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you mean simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation I have only read the instructions on how to do it via WIFI.
Would that be an option for you?

If so please refer to https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/07-Testing-on-physical-iDevices

Comment: Hi Lasse, yes I have seen that doc and tried it successfully. But no luck so far with multiple devices.

Comment: Okay, I just read this thread from the ios-calabash google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/23F5QuBvsyY that with instruments you can only launch one. Unless if you run multiple instances(multiple machines or VM setup).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running Calabash over virtual machines, but I found the networking to be an issue since all VMs need to be on the same network.  I was using one of my Macs wifi as an access point and for some reason, the devices kept losing their connection.   I switched to using separate machines, and a router for my access point, and figured out how to build an IPA with the directions provided by the Calabash devs for testing on physical devices, then use ideviceinstaller (installed using homebrew) and able to test on multiple devices using the net/ssh gem to connect to them.  There's a few environment variables to configure per session but its pretty solid once you get it going.