# Run multiple devices in parallel on Calabash iOS

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

Is there any work around to run multiple iOS devices in parallel with calabash-iOS as we have limitation with instruments to run only single instance at once. Any help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  Until Apple allows/supports multiple instances of instruments you will only be able test on one device at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by our colleague, no.
However, you can test your app in multiple physical devices at once, or, test it in one emulated device and physical devices at once.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the parallel-calabash gem.  I'm communicating with multiple devices using a mac machine per ios device setup.

A brief description of my setup is described in my post here [Running multiple devices with calabash ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403142/running-multiple-devices-with-calabash-ios/39576369#39576369)